# How do I lubricate plastic rollers for sliding closet doors?

Tags: doors, lubrication

I just installed some new sliding closet doors, but unfortunately they're a bit squeaky/noisy when operating. They are "Reliabilt" doors from Lowes, the actual company that makes these is [SGA](http://sga.ca). There's nothing in the instructions and nothing on their website about suggested maintenance/lubrication.

I'm not entirely sure what the rollers are made of, they're some kind of plastic or nylon rollers that fit in an extruded aluminum track.

[image: roller]
[image: mounted doors]

What kind of lubricant can I use that won't break down the plastic, or gum it up over time from dust/etc?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any dry silicon spray lube will be fine also.  Do not use and petroleum based lubes or WD40. Wet type lubes attract dirt and dust and get very messy. Same advise goes for door hinges.

Comment: Ended up using "jig a loo" which is silicon-based (the box store I went to surprisingly didn't have a huge selection). Seems to have done the trick, hopefully stands the test of time.

Comment: Any time it starts to bind a bit, give it a shot!!!

Comment: It's been well over a year, no problems at all. A few days ago actually I gave them a quick spray but only because I had a squeak in a door (not these ones) and so went around and lubricated all the hinges and such.

Comment: Glad to hear you had good success with the silicon lube. It is the only product I will use on hinges, windows and locks.

Answer (score 9):

A PTFE (aka Teflon<sup>®</sup>) spray such as [this](http://www.lowes.com/pd_124699-39963-D00100101_0__?zipCode=97217&firstReferURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lowes.com%2Fpd_124699-39963-D00100101_0__%3FproductId%3D1007929%26Ntt%3Dsilicone%2Blubricant%26pl%3D1%26currentURL%3D%252Fpl__0__s%253FNtt%253Dsilicone%252Blubricant&catalogId=10051&productId=1007929&pl=1&findStoreErrorURL=StoreLocatorDisplayView&selectedLocalStoreBeanArray=%5Bcom.lowes.commerce.storelocator.beans.LocatorStoreBean%4047ca2d78%2C+com.lowes.commerce.storelocator.beans.LocatorStoreBean%404f606d75%2C+com.lowes.commerce.storelocator.beans.LocatorStoreBean%404c8eed75%2C+com.lowes.commerce.storelocator.beans.LocatorStoreBean%404caf6d75%2C+com.lowes.commerce.storelocator.beans.LocatorStoreBean%4033906d72%5D&currentURL=%2Fpl__0__s%3FNtt%3Dsilicone%2Blubricant&Ntt=silicone+lubricant&URL=TopCategoriesDisplayView&langId=-1&storeId=10151) should do the trick.  They're widely available, and in several brands so you should be able to find one easily.

The squeak comes mostly from the roller turning around its axle, so I spray a little in between them and spin the roller a few times to distribute it.  Clean up any excess with a paper towel.  I don't have problems with them getting clogged with dust (and I think I have more than my fair share of dust!).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is powdered graphite, available at any home store in a little tube for about 2 bucks - a tiny bit squirted into the roller/axle area, if that is where the squeak is coming from. This works great for door hinges as well, and does not have the disadvantages of spray oils like WD40 (sticky, wears away quickly, etc).

Answer (score 0):

We just moved into a Mission Viejo 1987 ranch style home. It has lots of wood with nylon rollers on closets and cabinet doors etc. I have found that ArmorAll Original is the best lubricant for the nylon rollers and parts. Inexpensive, easy to apply, cleans and lubricates. It seems to not collect any debris afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Lowes has a Item # 650814 Model # 12007, "3-IN-ONE 2-oz Lock Lube"

I bought it based on these recommendations.

The short "hose"/nozzle let me spray the wheels in place, and 4 closets later, they're quiet and noticeably easier to close.

Answer (score -1):

I actually used a candle I rubbed the candle all over the sliders . It worked great .