# How can I get my new closet door rollers to roll?

Tags: closet

Recently, I installed two new tracks for two closets (both with two sliding doors a piece). The first track works great.  The second track is having some issues, the back door rolls nicely,the front door moves but the rollers inside the track will not roll.

I have checked to see if something is obstructing the door from rolling on the rollers and cannot for the life of me find anything obstructing.  Tried lubricating due to this post, but no luck there.

[How do I lubricate plastic rollers for sliding closet doors?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4847/how-do-i-lubricate-plastic-rollers-for-sliding-closet-doors)

[image: Image of the roller]

Basically, what seems to be occurring it is as if the wheels are stuck as they do not turn when the door is slid, so the door will slide but it is rather loud.  So, I pushed up with the door and I was able to turn the wheels so it is not like the wheels themselves are stuck.

I have also tried readjusting the roller bracket positioning several time just to see if that would help, but no luck there either.

Comment: Is your door pulling heavily on these wheels? Is the frame perfectly parallel top and bottom? Is the track bent at any spot?

Comment: is the door installed correctly, you may have put the door on the wrong track

Comment: @alt Door seems to be pulling heavy on the wheels but that is largely due to the wheels not turning.  The frame is probably not perfectly parallel, but the back door slides this is just the front door.  Track is not bent.  At this point I am guessing it is the rollers.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Door seems to be installed correctly, it is a dual track so technically you could put either door on either track, it is just a matter of where you want them.  The roller brackets themselves have to be on a specific track and they are on the correct track required for the brackets.